# IMPDP uses more disk space than expected

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, rhel, datapump, impdp

**Background**:

I've been tasked with importing a large amount of data from a production database to a test database (Oracle 12c release 2 running on RHEL) and I'm using Data Pump.

The first time I imported the tables, The tables were created and the data was imported as planned, but - due to an issue in my data pump parameter file - the constraints were not imported.

My subsequent attempts did not go as well, however. Data Pump began to freeze part way and the `STATUS` command showed that no bytes were being processed.

**My Solution Attempts**:

I tried using `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE` and dropping the tables directly after an attempt. I also dropped the master tables of any data pump jobs I was unable to terminate from the utility.

Still, it seemed to hang earlier and earlier in the process as I continuously tried to import the tables. `df -h` returned 100% disk usage every time it hanged.

The dump file itself is on a separate drive so it's no longer taking up room. I've been trying to clear out space but it keeps filling up when I run a job and I can't tell where. Oracle flashbacks are disabled and I made sure to purge the oracle recycle bin.

**tl;dr**:

Running impdp jobs seems to use up disk space beyond the added tables and the job master tables. Where is this memory getting used up and what can I do to clear it for a succesful import?

Comment: Check trace directory from  `SELECT VALUE FROM V$DIAG_INFO WHERE NAME = 'Diag Trace';` and dump directory `SELECT VALUE FROM V$DIAG_INFO WHERE NAME = 'Diag Cdump';`

Comment: Unfortunately the cdump directory was empty and the trace directory only used 355Mb. The total dumpfile is about 40G. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

The database was in `archivelog mode` in order to set up streams and recovery manager backups. As a result, `impdp` was causing a flood of archived database changes.

In order to clear out the old archives I ran the following in `rman` for every database in `noarchivelog mode` on the server.

```
connect target /
run { 
allocate channel c1 type disk; 
delete force noprompt archivelog until time 'SYSDATE-30'; 
release channel c1; 
}
```

This cleared up 60 gigabytes. I also added the parameter `transform=disable_archive_logging:Y` to my `impdp` parameter file. This suppresses archive creation when running data pump imports.